# microturbine heat loss

Tags: heat-engine

Would the hot combustion gasses in the millimeter-wide turbine in

http://thefutureofthings.com/3063-engine-on-a-chip/

lose heat so quickly that the engine efficiency would be low?

The velocity of the gas is relativly constant for any turbine size (approaching the speed of sound). However, thermal diffusion moves faster on smaller distance scales (the speed scales as the inverse-square-root of distance). Thus, heat would be lost to and through the walls more quickly in comparison to the airflow, which means less energy to do work. Is this more of an issue on smaller scales?